# How to use ProcessMitigationOptionsMask parameter in GetProcessMitigationPolicy() function call?

Tags: c, winapi, windows-10

I'm trying to see if I can query all execution mitigation policies for a process in one call to `GetProcessMitigationPolicy()` function (or similarly set them via a call to `SetProcessMitigationPolicy()` function) instead of doing them individually, one-by-one.

The [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh769085(v=vs.85).aspx) suggests using `ProcessMitigationOptionsMask` parameter for that, but I'm not really sure how to use it, or what mask are they referring to?

Can someone show an example?

Comment: you can not query more than one Mitigation Policy per call. the `MitigationPolicy`- this is not bitmask but enum value. you can set only one value. what is returned by `ProcessMitigationOptionsMask` not quit clear, but you can see that in any (except `ProcessMitigationOptionsMask`) input/output structure for 3-rd parameter `lpBuffer` exist `DWORD  Flags;` member. i think that returned the mask of valid bits of this `Flags`

Comment: @RbMm: Yeah, I'm not sure. In my case it seems to always return `0x3330:0x3333333333333303` on the latest RTM build of Win10.

Comment: I view `0x7777777777777777` (not latest win10) but anyway you can not query more than one policy option per call

Comment: @RbMm: You know, although each of the `MitigationPolicy` parameters is an enum, the values they represent are bitmasks. So my assumption was that this `ProcessMitigationOptionsMask` parameter would somehow combine all of those bits into one 128-bit value. But I guess not. In either case it would be nice to know what that parameter does, if anyone knows?

Comment: anyway - which data you query ? you need and can set only one query type.

Comment: MSDN does say "An application can set many mitigation options without querying the operating system for mitigation options by combining bitwise with the mask to exclude all non-supported bits at once" and I thought I could do `ULONG64 bits = (1 << ProcessASLRPolicy) & optionsmask;` but that does not work. (ProcessMitigationOptionsMask is just 64 bits on Windows 8). Unfortunately MSDN uses the text from GetProcessMitigationPolicy to descript Set as well. You could report the issue on MSDN and hope they fix it.

Comment: @Anders: Sure, but where do you report it?

Comment: @c00000fd One option is the "Was this helpful thing" at the bottom of some MSDN pages, click no and you can input some text. There is also a SDK blog and some (at)Microsoft.com email address I don't remember off the top of my head. The new learn.microsoft.com site lets you comment and edit as well but not everything has been moved there yet.